# How to get model data annotations to implement application validation without implementing at DB level as well using EF?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, validation, entity-framework-4

I like the idea of using the data annotations to specify validation of fields within the Model. However in EF I notice that it wants to implement this at DB level ie [Required] becomes a "not null" field. Is it possible to just have the application apply this validation without changing the database?

Thanks,

Ed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is to use a separate view model for the views and separate entity classes for the database. And you can map those objects using a library like [auto mapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/).

Comment: Thanks for this. However I am a bit confused as to whether EF should be embedding these validations into the DB by default. I am wondering whether there is some setting which ensures that these Data Annotations just work from the Model and not from the DB.

Comment: I am just wondering whether this situation has been created by the fact I am using EF Code First. Thanks, Ed

Comment: Any way , using the same entity classes as the MVC view models is not a good practice. Because view model is just a representation of your data. It will be change view to another view. But domain entity model will be the same.

Comment: You can override default mapping in your context class.

Comment: Thanks for the above. I have picked up on this overriding mechanism within the context class, but I have not come across a method to prevent the validation rules being implemented in the DB as yet.

Comment: what you can do is to use, `modelBuilder.Entity<YourEntity>()
    .HasOptional(t => t.Property)`

Comment: Just found out something that solves this in a simple way. Basically comment out the "SetInitializer" in Global.asa and rename the table "EdmMetadata" to say "EdmMetadataXXX". Add a [Required] annotation into the model and this will still validate and the DB field is still nullable. I do realise the next time you want to sync up other features then this could get overwritten, but just an idea.

Comment: what you can do is to use, modelBuilder.Entity<YourEntity>() .HasOptional(t => t.Property) .... This is the same as [NotMapped] which is not quite to do with my validation issue, since this simply stops a property being implemented at DB level. Am I correct?

Comment: Sorry my mistake IsOptional is the opposite of IsRequired.

Comment: Also I have found that the following could be used to prevent the recreation of the DB: Database.SetInitialiser<DBContext>(null); which is proabably more eloquent than my renaming of the metadata table !!